# Why is Pandas read_excel working on its own, but not inside a class definition?

Tags: python, pandas, class

I am trying to build a file import class that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

class ScrFileParser:
    def __init__(self,report):
        file = os.path.join("/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/SCR/20200626_Daten_175D.xlsx")
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name="Messdaten")
            self.file = df.head()
        except:
            self.file = "What? "+str(sys.exc_info()[0])+" How? "+str(sys.exc_info()[1])+" File: "+file
```

I tested this bit

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file = os.path.join("/home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/SCR/20200626_Daten_175D.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name="Messdaten")
print(df.head())
```

on its own and it works like expected. However if it is used inside the class definition `self.file` ends up as

```
What? <class 'SystemExit'> How? 1 File: /home/stage/sharOnStoNe/plotary/media/SCR/20200626_Daten_175D.xlsx
```

Why is this import working on its own, but not inside the class definiton?

Comment: Could you remove the `try:...except:...` part and just read the file and try to set it to self.file? This should give a more concrete error message, which might point to the problem.

Comment: I tried to do `self.file = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name="Messdaten")` but this seems not to work. The `file` is not set this way.

Comment: I meant to set `file` the way you did, but then directly invoking `df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name="Messdaten")` and `self.file = df.head()` without the `try`, and delete the last two lines. At the moment, the `try: ... except:` masks the error, so we are left to guessing what goes wrong.

Comment: Okay I will try that.

Comment: Hi @JakobBorchardt thanks for your input. I think I found the problem. It is not in my class definition or the pandas import, but rather it seems that Plotly's Dash, where I call the class definition from, has some kind of timeout defined and my import takes to long.